# Finding number of unique values (quickly) across a large data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a 1.5Mx7 `data.table` that I need to process through. The code I have written is running very slowly (.18s per row, estimated 75 hours to complete), and I'm hoping I can optimize it.

I'll put the pseudo-example code at the end, because it's long.

```
str(review)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1500000 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ user_id     : Factor w/ 375000 levels "aA1aJ9lJ1lB5yH5uR6jR7",..: 275929 313114 99332 277686 57473 31780 236964 44371 210127 217770 ...
 $ stars       : int  2 1 3 3 1 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ business_id : Factor w/ 60000 levels "aA1kR2bK6nH8yQ9gU2uI9",..: 40806 29885 43018 58297 58444 31626 26018 2493 37883 34204 ...
 $ votes.funny : int  3 0 0 7 2 9 6 8 2 7 ...
 $ votes.useful: int  4 1 0 5 9 2 4 7 4 9 ...
 $ votes.cool  : int  5 3 6 8 3 2 0 8 10 9 ...
 $ IDate       : IDate, format: "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "IDate"
```

I need to subset the dataset by date, and then compute several columns by `business_id`.

```
setkey(review, IDate)

system.time(
  review[
    #(IDate >= window.start) & (IDate <= window.end),
    1:10,
    .SD, 
    keyby = business_id
  ][
    ,
    list(
      review.num = .N,
      review.users = length(unique(user_id)),
      review.stars = mean(stars),
      review.votes.funny = sum(votes.funny),
      review.votes.useful = sum(votes.useful),
      review.votes.cool = sum(votes.cool)
    ),
    by = business_id
  ]
)

   user  system elapsed 
  1.534   0.000   1.534
```

Timing for smaller versions of the example dataset is

```
# 1% of original size - 15000 rows
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02 

# 10% of original size - 150000 rows
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.00    0.25
```

So, even though I'm only processing 10 rows, the time increases with the size of the original dataset.

I tried commenting out the `review.users` variable above, and the computation time on the original dataset fell tremendously:

```
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

So, my challenge is making `unique()` work more quickly.

I need to count the unique values in `user_id` for each grouping of `business_id`.

Not sure what else to specify, but I'm happy to answer questions.

---

Here is some code to create a pseudo-example dataset. I'm not sure exactly what is the cause of the slowdown, so I've tried to recreate the data as specifically as possible, but because the processing time for the random variables is so long I've reduced the size by ~90%.

```
z <- c()
x <- c()

for (i in 1:6000) {
  z <<- c(z, paste0(
    letters[floor(runif(7, min = 1, max = 26))],
    LETTERS[floor(runif(7, min = 1, max = 26))],
    floor(runif(7, min = 1, max = 10)),
    collapse = ""
  ))
}

z <- rep(z, 25)

for (i in 1:37500) {
  x <<- c(x, paste0(
    letters[floor(runif(7, min = 1, max = 26))],
    LETTERS[floor(runif(7, min = 1, max = 26))],
    floor(runif(7, min = 1, max = 10)),
    collapse = ""
  ))
}

x <- rep(x, 4)

review2 <- data.table(
  user_id = factor(x),
  stars = as.integer(round(runif(150000) * 5, digits = 0)),
  business_id = factor(z),
  votes.funny = as.integer(round(runif(150000) * 10, digits = 0)),
  votes.useful = as.integer(round(runif(150000) * 10, digits = 0)),
  votes.cool = as.integer(round(runif(150000) * 10, digits = 0)),
  IDate = rep(as.IDate("2012-01-01"), 150000)
)

setkey(review2, IDate)
```

Comment: I didn't read all that, but from your title, maybe you want `uniqueN`?

Comment: That's the one. Thanks @Frank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this - an alternative to unique using an extra data.table within an anonymous function:

```
review2[,{

  uid <- data.table(user_id)
  rev_user <- uid[, .N, by = user_id][, .N]

  #browser()
  list(
    review.num = .N,
    review.users = rev_user,
    review.stars = mean(stars),
    review.votes.funny = sum(votes.funny),
    review.votes.useful = sum(votes.useful),
    review.votes.cool = sum(votes.cool)
)}, by = business_id]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `length(unique())` is inefficient in calculating the length of factor variables as levels become very large.

Using `uniqueN()` instead (thanks @Frank):

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.12    0.00    0.12
```

Using `set(review, NULL, "user_id", as.character(review$user_id))` and `length(unique))`:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.11    0.00    0.11
```

Comment: `uniqueN` will most likely be optimised to be much faster in the next release (v1.9.8).